# Facebook Send button issue with title and description

Tags: facebook

I am using Facebook Send button in 3 pages of my website. Before i send the message, the title, website and description looks fine. After i send, it shows up  different title and different description in the message . I have no idea what's wrong in here? Is that my mistake somewhere or cache issue or something else?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: check it with http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ to see what facebook makes of your meta tags.

Comment: What is the code you are using for the send button? Did you make sure you are setting the proper url?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a tool called URL Linter. This tool gives us an idea about how a url will be shared on facebook, what content, which image will be fetched.  We can use this tool for any url and it fetches the latest title, description, excerpt and other stuff that will be shown while sharing the link. If you use an already shared URL with this tool then facebook fetches the latest content, and also updates it cache with the latest content.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to cross check and confirm that the url shared is of the right page, not the simple domain address. It will be better to cross check the following contents inside `<Head>` tag to make sure that you have done basic code requirements.

```
<link href="{URL OF THE PAGE}" rel="canonical">

<meta content="{YOUR FB APP ID}" property="fb:app_id">
<meta content="{YOUR PAGE TITLE}" property="og:title">
<meta content="website" property="og:type">
<meta content="{URL OF THE PAGE}" property="og:url">

<meta content="{LOGO IMAGE URL}" property="og:image">
<meta content="{YOUR SITE NAME}" property="og:site_name">
```

Once this is done, it should mostly resolve your issue with different title and different description.

If you still face issue, go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Input URL or Access Token and click DEBUG button. It will guide you if there is any errors in the in accessing the page by facebook.

Hope this helps.